# Webpack encore process not defined

Tags: symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I am trying to add JS functionality to a project that needs env variables to work properly. Basic project structure is as

```
- assets/ (cs / js)
- src/ (php stuff)
.env
webpack.config.js
```

When I add `process.env.key` to js files in assets I get `error  'process' is not defined` running yarn build/dev/watch.

I have tried following suggestions found:

1. [dotenv](https://ideneal.medium.com/how-to-export-symfony-4-environment-variables-into-front-end-application-with-encore-ed45463bee5a)
2. [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack)
3. [this other example](https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/567)

But all result in 'process not defined' on compile.

What might I be missing here? How do I debug the yarn build process?